# RabbitMQ rabbitmqctl command fails to initialize

Tags: rabbitmq

It seems I can run the `rabbitmq-server` command fine and it starts up but `rabbitmqctl` fails with an error so I can't stop it or do anything else.

```
~/rabbit/rabbitmq_server-3.7.15/sbin> rabbitmqctl
escript: exception error: undefined function rabbitmqctl_escript:main/1
  in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 758)
  in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
  in call from init:start_em/1
  in call from init:do_boot/3
```

This is with Erlang/OTP 22 `Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]`

Am I missing a config or something?

Comment: What operating system? How did you install Erlang and RabbitMQ?

Comment: SLES and OTP was built from source: https://www.erlang.org/downloads rabbit was just a download and untar.

Comment: Double-check your generic unix package's checksum: `$ sha256sum rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-3.7.15.tar.xz 
4d70e4d057c6e40022369584626fd7c2bdaa24997aae5cc7f8f182c6d46456cf  rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-3.7.15.tar.xz`

Comment: Also, what is the output of `which -a rabbitmqctl` when you are in the `sbin` dir?

Comment: `> sha256sum rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-3.7.15.tar.xz
4d70e4d057c6e40022369584626fd7c2bdaa24997aae5cc7f8f182c6d46456cf  rabbitmq-server-generic-unix-3.7.15.tar.xz` and it doesn't matter how I run it... in that case I put it in my path but it always does the same regardless
`~/rabbit/rabbitmq_server-3.7.15> ./sbin/rabbitmqctl
escript: exception error: undefined function rabbitmqctl_escript:main/1
  in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 758)
  in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
  in call from init:start_em/1
  in call from init:do_boot/3
`

Comment: I would like to see the output of `which -a rabbitmqctl` when you haven't moved commands around. Also, `which -a erl` and `which -a escript`. I regularly run RabbitMQ this way for testing and development and have never seen this issue.

Comment: Without it in the path, it doesn't find it...
`mb@localhost:~/rabbit/rabbitmq_server-3.7.15> which -a rabbitmqctl
which: no rabbitmqctl in (/home/mb/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/other/opt/java11/bin:/home/mb/opt/node/bin:/home/mb/local/bin)
mb@localhost:~/rabbit/rabbitmq_server-3.7.15> which -a erl
/home/mb/local/bin/erl
mb@localhost:~/rabbit/rabbitmq_server-3.7.15> which -a escript
/home/mb/local/bin/escript`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95678/discussion-between-luke-bakken-and-michaelb).

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have mismatched binaries. For example, let's say your system has outdated versions of RabbitMQ and/or Erlang, installed via your package manager. If you then download the current version of RabbitMQ, such as the generic binary release, and try to run it, your `$PATH` may point to the outdated version of Erlang elsewhere on your system.

The solution (particularly if you don't have root access), is to install the correct version of Erlang and the update your `$PATH` to ensure that the `sbin` directory under RabbitMQ and the `erl` executable of the newer Erlang are ahead of any other directory that might point to the older versions.